# String and pulley problem doubt

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

[image: Pulley is smooth and light. Even the string is light.]

When we apply a constant force on the massless string as described in the left image, the tension 
T = F. My doubt : isn't applying constant force similar to a block m2 hanging in the 2nd image. What is the difference between applying a constant force and hanging a block Instead of it ?

Comment: $T$ is not equal to $m_2g$ in the drawing on the right.  Also note - $T$ only equals $F$ in the drawing on the left if the block is moving at constant velocity.

Comment: @DavidWhite $T=F$ on the left side by construction. It just doesn't equal $mg$ unless the velocity is constant.

Comment: @RickGoldstein, what I'm trying to convey to the OP is that the he needs to be careful when comparing the two situations.  A proper free body diagram for the picture on the right clearly indicates that $T$ is not equal to $m_2g$, which appears to be the inference that the OP is trying to draw.

Comment: @DavidWhite That is true, and is more or less what I put in my answer. My comment was about your second assertion, which was not correct.

Comment: @RickGoldstein Thank you for your time. Now, what if I say that due to the constant force on the left image kinetic energy of the mass M has increased. Will T be equal to F now?

Comment: @PratheekRPai The fact that $T=F$ in the left hand diagram is true independent of whether the mass is accelerating. It's a consequence of the assumption that the rope is massless (in the real world, that isn't true, of course, but we usually make a lot of simplifying assumptions when we start learning physics). Because the rope is massless, the applied force *is* the tension. The mass accelerates based on the total force on it, which is the difference between the tension and the gravitational force (since they are in opposite directions).

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is totally understandable, but you're missing one piece: the inertia of $m_2$. In the left hand diagram, the constant force, $F$, is applied only to the mass, $m$. In the right hand diagram, the constant force on the left side of the pulley, $m_2g$, is applied to $m_2$, and, through the tension, effectively also applied to $m_1$. If we make free-body diagrams for both masses and consider their accelerations, we get

$$F_1 = m_1a_1 = m_1g-T$$
and
$$F_2 = m_2a_2 = T-m_2g$$
where I've taken the positive direction of force and motion to be down on the right and up on the left. But $a_1=a_2$, so 
$$T = 2m_1m_2g/(m_1+m_2)$$.

When $m_1=m_2$, the tension is, indeed, equal to the force applied ($m_2g$). In that case, $m_2$ isn't accelerating, and its inertia is therefore not a factor.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an acceleration, as there is: in the second case, there is another force: m2*a that acts. Since you've shown that m2*g is accelerating downwards (acceleration points downwards), there'd be a pseudo force acting on block m2 in the upward direction. Thus T would be equal to m2*(a-g).